# Universal turing machine U should determine if M(x) stops

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

so we have a universal turing machine U, that should determine if a turing machine M with input x will stop. The solution should be presented in pseudo code.

can someone help me a bit out, who should i solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem):

> The halting problem can be stated as follows: "Given a description of an arbitrary computer program, decide whether the program finishes running or continues to run forever". This is equivalent to the problem of deciding, given a program and an input, whether the program will eventually halt when run with that input, or will run forever.
>
> Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist. A key part of the proof was a mathematical definition of a computer and program, what became known as a Turing machine; the halting problem is undecidable over Turing machines.

So no, it's not possible.

If you want, you can probably run `M` on `x` for a while. If it stops, we know it stops. If it doesn't stop, we don't really know whether or not it stops.